# Function extension of snackbar does not work in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have these `View` function extensions:

```
fun View.showSnackbar(msgId: Int, length: Int) {
    showSnackbar(context.getString(msgId), length)
}

fun View.showSnackbar(msg: String, length: Int) {
    showSnackbar(msg, length, null, {})
}

fun View.showSnackbar(
    msgId: Int,
    length: Int,
    actionMessageId: Int,
    action: (View) -> Unit
) {
    showSnackbar(context.getString(msgId), length, context.getString(actionMessageId), action)
}

fun View.showSnackbar(
    msg: String,
    length: Int,
    actionMessage: CharSequence?,
    action: (View) -> Unit
) {
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(this, msg, length)
    if (actionMessage != null) {
        snackbar.setAction(actionMessage) {
            action(this)
        }.show()
    }
}
```

I tried to use it in my fragment, but the `Snackbar` does not show. It does not crash, it simply does not show. However, my `showSnackbar2()` works. Here is how I use it in my fragment:

```
class AddressesFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddressesBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentAddressesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.buttonSnackbar.setOnClickListener {view ->
            //showSnackbar1() // DOES NOT WORK!!
            showSnackbar2()
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    fun showSnackbar1() {
        binding.buttonSnackbar.showSnackbar(
            R.string.location_permission_granted,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
        )
    }

    fun showSnackbar2() {
        val view = activity?.findViewById(android.R.id.content) as View
        Snackbar.make(
            view,
            R.string.location_permission_granted,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
}
```

How can I fix my function extension so that `showSnackbar1()` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Snackbar` is not being shown, because you have a checking `if (actionMessage != null)`. If `actionMessage == null`, `Snackbar` will not be shown. Please check the detailed explanation below:

```
fun View.showSnackbar(msgId: Int, length: Int) { // when you called showSnackbar1() this method was called.
    showSnackbar(context.getString(msgId), length)
}

fun View.showSnackbar(msg: String, length: Int) { // Then it goes here with some msg: String and length: Int you passed from the method above
    showSnackbar(msg, length, null, {})
}

fun View.showSnackbar(
    msg: String, // msg from context.getString(msgId)
    length: Int, // Length you passed from your fragment
    actionMessage: CharSequence?, // !!! this param is NULL, because you passed NULL
    action: (View) -> Unit
) {
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(this, msg, length)
    if (actionMessage != null) { // !!! since actionMessage is null, this method is not being called
        snackbar.setAction(actionMessage) {
            action(this)
        }.show()
    }
}
```

So you need to pass action message in the last method in order to show your `Snackbar` or extract `show()` call from that checking:

```
fun View.showSnackbar(
    msg: String, // msg from context.getString(msgId)
    length: Int, // Length you passed from your fragment
    actionMessage: CharSequence?, // !!! this param is NULL, because you passed NULL
    action: (View) -> Unit
) {
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(this, msg, length)
    if (actionMessage != null) {
        snackbar.setAction(actionMessage) {
            action(this)
        }
    }
    snackbar.show()
}
```

Comment: a pull request has been made for this issue https://github.com/android/permissions-samples/pull/82

Comment: these codes are archived. use this instead: https://github.com/android/platform-samples/tree/main/samples/privacy/permissions

Answer (score 0):

This extension function works. It extends the View object and calls Snackbar object:

```
fun View.showSnackbar(msg: String,
                      length: Int,
                      actionMessage: CharSequence?,) {
    Snackbar.make(this, msg, length).show()
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
val view = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content) as View
view.showSnackbar("Hi", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG, null)

// Or
binding.buttonSnackbar.showSnackbar("Hi", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG, null)
```